# Как открыть нужный слайд в owl-carousel2 по клику?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, materialize-css

При клике по ссылке мне нужно открыть в модальном окне (на `materialize-css`) определенный слайд. Пытаюсь сделать как [здесь](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/urlhashnav.html#ten),  но открывается все равно первый слайд. Вот код:

```
    <!-- OWL-Carousel -->
        var owl_doctor = $("#doctors_slider");
        owl_doctor.owlCarousel({
          loop: true,
          nav: false,
          URLhashListener:true,
          autoplayHoverPause:true,
          startPosition: 'URLHash'
          }
        });

    <!-- мой слайдер -->
    <div id="doctors_slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme doctor_slider">
            <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'Specialists',
                    'post_per_page' => -1,
                    'order' => 'asc',
                        );
                $specialists = new WP_Query( $args ); 

                $counter = 0;

                if( $specialists->have_posts() ) {
                    while ($specialists->have_posts() ) {
                    $specialists->the_post(); $counter++ ?>
                <!-- слайды -->
                <div class="doctors_slider__item" data-hash="slide-<?php echo $counter; ?>" id="slide-<?php echo $counter; ?>"></div>
</div>
    <!-- ссылка по которой открывается слайд в модальном окне -->
    <a class="modal-trigger certificate_trigger" data-target="modal3" href="#slide-<?php echo $counter; ?>">Подробнее</a>
```

Comment: уберите php и сделайте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: php там абсолютно не мешает, тут явно дело в другом, надо открыть модалку с нужным слайдом